# File corruption prevention strategy

Tags: linux, filesystems, data-recovery

I recently read about BTRFS and it's superiority in terms of error handling and noticed that I have no real plan in case data corruption happens, other than backing up regularly.

I am not asking for advice on an enterprise level, but in what kind of ways would you protect yourself against data corruption as a home user who has data he/she can't afford to lose. Or if you do it all?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use daily backups to two external devices and one cloud backup. That being said, only information that isn't sensitive ends up in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from just Backing them up make sure all SSD's (Internal or External) have very strong ECC like Crucial P5 or Samsungs Evo Series, while all Medium and High Level SSD's have some form they often do not stipulate it which often means is very weak/poor performing!

Cheap SSD's especially DRAMless DO NOT HAVE ECC!!!

Comment: Please be more specific with your answers. E.g. explain what ECC is.